# Maven Build Failure for chat-jc sample of spring security 4.0

Tags: maven, spring-security

There was maven build failure when I tried to compile chat-jc sample of spring security 4.0

First, I downloaded the sample code with this command.

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security.git
```

After, I changed directory to /samples/chat-jc and 'mvn compile'.
And I got this result

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.springframework.security:spring-security-samples-chat-jc:war:4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 246, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spring-security-samples-chat-jc 4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/1.2.7.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-1.2.7.RELEASE.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/redis/embedded/embedded-redis/0.2/embedded-redis-0.2.pom
[WARNING] The POM for redis.embedded:embedded-redis:jar:0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/1.2.7.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/redis/embedded/embedded-redis/0.2/embedded-redis-0.2.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.366 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-29T07:40:37+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-security-samples-chat-jc: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.security:spring-security-samples-chat-jc:war:4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE, redis.embedded:embedded-redis:jar:0.2: Failure to find org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE in https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-snasphot has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And I could not find both information of

```
org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE
redis.embedded:embedded-redis:jar:0.2
```

on the http://search.maven.org/

How can I succeed to compile this project?

Thanks for your reading......

Comment: I think the pom has been left outdated; try setting both `thymeleaf `and `thymeleaf-spring4` to version `2.1.4.RELEASE`

Comment: I changed version and thymeleaf-spring4 problem solved. But I still have problem with embedded-redis. Thank you @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ

Comment: Thanks for the report. I have added https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pom has been left outdated; try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orange.redis-embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

for redis (they changed groupId, 0.6 is the latest version; you might want to try 0.4, or 0.3.8 if it does not compile).

Also use version `2.1.4.RELEASE` for both `thymeleaf` and `thymeleaf-spring4`